# Error :“the command '/bin/sh -c source protected-env/bin/activate' returned a non-zero code: 127” while I'm trying to configure my first dockerfile

Tags: bash, command-line, python, docker

I'm trying to learn docker. This is my first experiment. I have written this dockerfile :

```
FROM nvidia/cudagl:11.3.0-base-ubuntu20.04

LABEL Author="ZioMario"
LABEL Title="Firefox/Docker20.10.6/Ubuntu20.04"

# Enviorment variables

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV PATH "$PATH:/bin/2.82/python/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
ENV FIREFOX_PATH "/bin/2.82"
ENV FIREFOXPIP "/bin/2.82/python/bin/pip3"
ENV FIREFOXPY "/bin/2.82/python/bin/python3.7m"
ENV HW="GPU"

# Install dependencies

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
    apt-utils \
    wget \ 
    libopenexr-dev \ 
    bzip2 \ 
    build-essential \ 
    zlib1g-dev \ 
    libxmu-dev \ 
    libxi-dev \ 
    libxxf86vm-dev \ 
    libfontconfig1 \ 
    libxrender1 \ 
    libgl1-mesa-glx \ 
    xz-utils \
    firefox \
    openjdk-8-jre

# Download the Python source

RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tgz \ 
    && tar -xzf Python-3.7.0.tgz \ 
    && cp -r Python-3.7.0/Include/* $FIREFOX_PATH/python/include/python3.7m/ \ 
    && rm -rf Python-3.7.0.tgz \ 
    && rm -rf Python-3.7.0 

# Installing a modern version of numpy

RUN rm -rf ${FIREFOX_PATH}/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy 

# Must first ensurepip to install Firefox pip3 and then new numpy

RUN ${FIREFOXPY} -m venv protected-env

RUN source protected-env/bin/activate

RUN ${FIREFOXPY} -m ensurepip && ${FIREFOXPIP} install --upgrade pip && ${FIREFOXPIP} install numpy
RUN deactivate

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /
```

Unfortunately it does not work. This is the error that I'm getting :

**The command '/bin/sh -c source protected-env/bin/activate' returned a non-zero code: 127**

the wrong line is this :

**RUN source protected-env/bin/activate**

Do you have any idea about how to fix it ? thanks.

Comment: You tagged this `bash`, however as you can see from the error message, docker `RUN` is using `/bin/sh` - which does not recognize the `source` command

Comment: Besides, I think each RUN creates its own shell process. If I am right, whatever you source is only valid in that process and does not affect the other RUNs.

Comment: Crossposted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335797/error-the-command-bin-sh-c-source-protected-env-bin-activate-returned-a-no

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN source protected-env/bin/activate
```

makes no sense.

`activate` is a script that sets a few environment variables *for the current shell*; however, the current shell dies directl after sourcing that file. So, it has no effect. Especially, it has no effect on the next line!

Your error, however, stems from the fact that you're trying to run a **ba**sh script with sh, which doesn't work. Solution here is to put all these things (sourceing the activate file, installing things using pip) into a single shell script that starts with `#!/bin/bash`, so that it can be executed in one go, and then `COPY`ing it into your container image, then `RUN`ning that.

However, I've not yet encountered a reason to install numpy via pip. You should probably not do that, but install it using `apt`!

Same, and even more so, applies to python itself. Don't build that from source – I don't know where your guide is from, but seriously, that's a terrible idea. Your ubuntu  comes with Python3, most probably even preinstalled, or installable as `apt install python3`, done! In total, you'd just add `python3-numpy` to the end of your list of packages to install, and be done; no downloading python, no building it, and certainly no need to source some activate file and install numpy via pip!

Comment: I've read here : https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-virtualenv-dockerfile/
I'm not sure that it works...not tried yet


ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/protected-env
ENV PATH "$PATH:"$VIRTUAL_ENV:/bin:/bin/2.82/python/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
RUN ${FIREFOXPY} -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
Installing a modern version of numpy
RUN rm -rf ${FIREFOX_PATH}/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy
RUN ${FIREFOXPY} -m ensurepip && ${FIREFOXPIP} install --upgrade pip && ${FIREFOXPIP} install numpy

Comment: as said, multiple times, in my answer: you don't need any of that virtualenv stuff. really. stop trying to solve problems that you only have because you've found guides online that you're not understanding. I literally wrote what you need to do (add python3-numpy to your list of packages that you install using `apt`, remove **all the rest** of your dockerfile, since its senseless)

Comment: without virtual env I get this warning : WARNING: Running pip as root will break packages and permissions. You should install packages reliably by using venv: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

Comment: ... you still didn't read what I wrote. You don't need to run pip at all. You *should* not run pip at all.

Comment: Do you like to get shortcuts. Me too,sometimes. Most frequently I want to solve problems directly.

Comment: you're not solving any problems by not even reading and trying to understand the answers you get, I'm afraid.

Comment: man,don't be so severe with me. I'm trying to do my best. You don't know that this is my hobby,not my job.

Comment: I'm not being severe; I must've spent more than an hour communicating with you, and you've not felt compelled to actually try and understand what I've tried to explain, so I must admit that maybe I should let you enjoy your hobby without my help :)

Comment: oh yes,you are severe.